# For $L \gt 0$, $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)=L \rightarrow \lim_{x \to \infty}\sqrt{f(x)}=\sqrt{L}$

Tags: limits, solution-verification

I aim to prove the following statement:

> For $L \gt 0$, $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)=L \rightarrow \lim_{x \to \infty}\sqrt{f(x)}=\sqrt{L}$

I will use these two lemmas:

> $ \vert \sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b} \vert \leq \sqrt{ \vert a -b \vert } \quad \dagger$

> for $x,y \gt 0$: $\quad x \gt y \leftrightarrow x^2 \gt y^2 \quad \dagger\dagger$

---

For notation purposes:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)=L \iff \forall \epsilon \gt 0 \ \exists N \in \mathbb R \text{ s.t. } \forall x \in \mathbb R \big [ x \gt N \rightarrow \lvert f(x) - L \rvert \lt \epsilon \big ]$$

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\sqrt{f(x)}=\sqrt{L} \iff \forall \epsilon \gt 0 \ \exists P \in \mathbb R \text{ s.t. } \forall x \in \mathbb R \big [ x \gt P \rightarrow \Big\lvert \sqrt{f(x)} - \sqrt{L} \Big\rvert \lt \epsilon \big ]$$

For an arbitrary $\epsilon$, by assumption, we have:

$$\forall x \in \mathbb R \big [ x \gt N_{\epsilon^2} \rightarrow \lvert f(x) - L \rvert \lt \epsilon^2 \big]$$

For an arbitrary $x \gt N_{\epsilon^2}$, and by $\dagger \dagger$, we have that:

$$\lvert f(x) - L \rvert \lt \epsilon^2 \implies \sqrt{ \lvert f(x) - L \rvert} \lt \epsilon  $$

By $\dagger$, we have:

$$\Big \lvert \sqrt{f(x)} - \sqrt{L} \Big \rvert \leq \sqrt{ \lvert f(x) - L \rvert} $$

Thus we have:

$$\Big \lvert \sqrt{f(x)} - \sqrt{L} \Big \rvert \lt \epsilon$$

By letting $P = N_{\epsilon^2}$, we can guarantee that $\Big \lvert \sqrt{f(x)} - \sqrt{L} \Big \rvert \lt \epsilon \quad \quad\square$

Comment: @CSquared I have not learned about continuity yet

Comment: You need $L>0$. For $L=0$, $\sqrt {f(x)}$ need not even be defined.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Ahh, gotch ya. I'll edit accordingly. Cheers~

Comment: The proof is correct and well written in my opinion, good job.

Comment: A corollary to this (wherein the proof procedure is quite similar) is that: for $L \gt 0$, $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)=L \rightarrow \lim_{x \to a} \sqrt{f(x)} = \sqrt{L}$

Comment: Additionally, if we know that $\forall x \in \text{dom}(f)\Big[ f(x) \geq 0]$, we can actually relax our restriction on $L$ to say $L \geq 0$.